# Why do I get only 1 ItemAttachmentDeleting event when deleting more than 1 file in WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, event-receivers

I have this requirement, using WSS 3.0, that when an attachment is added or deleted from a list item, I need to send an email to the users.  I'm not having a problem with the emails; it's understanding how the following events work.  I'm using the following 4 events:

```
ItemAttachmentAdding, ItemAttachmentAdded, ItemAttachmentDeleting, ItemAttachmnetDeleted
```

If I add 2 attachments to an item, I get `ItemAttachmentAdding` and `ItemAttachmentAdded` fired for each attachment, which is what I expect.  But when I delete 2 attachments, I get `ItemAttachmentDeleting` and `ItemAttachmentDeleted` fired only once total (for both files).  I expect this to behave like the Adding/Added events; both events for each file deleted.  And unlike the Adding/Added events, I don't have access to the name of the attachments that were deleted.  Seems inconsistent.

Is this the correct behavior for these events?  And is there a way to identify the names of the attachments that were deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I've quickly checked on 2010 version - there's the SPItemEventProperties.BeforeUrl property (and corresponding SPItemEventProperties.AfterUrl property). On ItemAttachmentDeleting event SPItemEventProperties.BeforeUrl contains the url of the targeted attachment. I hope it works similar in 2007 version.

Unfortunately in the 2010 version ItemAttachmentDeleting event is being fired once for each attachment.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  On the AttachmentDelete/Deleting events, I'm seeing BeforeUrl as null.  On the AttachmentAdded/Adding events, BeforeUrl does contain the filename.  Either 3.0 is screwed up or it's me.  I'm glad to see it works in 2010 as I would expect it to.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck in 3.0 for awhile so I'll have to come up with some sort of work around.